# Error if I try to print invoices using fooman email attachment extension

Tags: magento-1.9, print

I am using Magento ver. 1.9.0.1. I have installed Fooman email attachment extension. Now I am trying to print an invoice from orders in admin. But facing following errors:

There has been an error processing your request

ImageType is not JPG

Trace:

```
#0 /magento/lib/Zend/Pdf/Resource/ImageFactory.php(62): Zend_Pdf_Resource_Image_Jpeg->__construct('/home/magento/...')
#1 /magento/lib/Zend/Pdf/Image.php(124): Zend_Pdf_Resource_ImageFactory::factory('/home/magento/...')
#2 /magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php(158): Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath('/home/magento/...')
#3 /magento/app/code/community/Fooman/EmailAttachments/Model/Order/Pdf/Order.php(49): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract->insertLogo(Object(Zend_Pdf_Page), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Store))
#4 /magento/app/code/community/Fooman/EmailAttachments/controllers/Admin/OrderController.php(64): Fooman_EmailAttachments_Model_Order_Pdf_Order->getPdf(Array)
#5 /magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Fooman_EmailAttachments_Admin_OrderController->pdfordersAction()
#6 /magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('pdforders')
#7 /magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#8 /magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#9 /magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#10 /magento/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#11 {main}
```

---

I have JPG and JPEG format logo uploaded in sales email admin.

Please help.

Comment: It currently looks like you are trying to print an order instead of an invoice. Does the invoice work? Does the printing of the invoice work with Email Attachments uninstalled? Does it work with a different image?

Comment: @max can you accept this answer to close out the post?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be a GIF image with the file name extension renamed to JPEG without the file type actually being converted.